# DoS by consuming all hosting trafic

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos, web-hosting

Given a small website hosted on a small data plan, is it possible for someone to keep doing requesting for my website URL or just an image hosted on my website that will consume all my permitted traffic and make the host eventually close access to the website?

Or do hosts have a mechanism to defend against this?

Comment: by the way, it's called DoS, not DnS. DNS stands for domain name server. And yes, it's possible IF your webhost doesn't have dos or ddos protection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of DoS attack it actually very easy to carry on and it could be as simple or as sophisticated as it get: it can be a simple as a [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) scripted loop, a spam campain using images hosted on your server, etc.

It is usually very easy to carry out because the resource attacked is usually quite small and can easily be completely consumed in a short time, even with limited bandwidth.

Note also that it can also happen without anyone deliberately attacking you: having a resource hosted on your site growing in popularity unexpectedly will have the same result (see [slashdot effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect) some something similar).

Defending against this is actually rather easy, at least for everything that is static content (usually most of your site): you put a [content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) in front of your web site and they will reduce drastically the effect of such attack against your site (many also offer other services too and they come in all kind of prices from free to awfully expensive).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer to your question is yes.

Mainly because it is a application layer attack, for which there seems to be less protection against these days.

For instance if someone uses a distributed approach (DDoS) to request your site, it would come of as many legitimate users (at least if they follow some kind of natural pattern).

There might be some countermeasures in place to detect typical DoS attacks as they could be the instance of one IP repeatedly fetching the same image. But I would not count on it as it is an application layer attack as opposed to other more classical DoS attacks that attempt to flood the victim with multiple types of traffic using amplification techniques on protocol-level such as NTP (network-time protocol) amplification, SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol) amplification, SYN Flood, and more recently mssql amplification.

A nice article on layer 7 DDoS attacks might be read here: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/layer-7-ddos-attacks-detection-mitigation/ where they walk you through it and suggest some mitigation approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can see logs about visits to your website. They should show what is going on. If you don't know where to find them, ask your provider. Maybe you have Direct Admin or Plesk as admin panel, and then you can see logs there.

It could very well be that you have one image hosted that is shown on another website. If that website gets a lot of traffic, the result is that the specific image is served many times. This is not an attack, but simple use or abuse. The webserver (normally Apache) has a setting not to serve images to third party websites. That would prevent this from happening.